# Switching views in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

One approach is that we change scenes in `Stage` using `setScene()` method.

Different one, is to set root of `Scene` using `setRoot()` method.

Which one to use and when? Are there any advantages/disadvantages and consenquences of using each one of those?

Comment: If you switch the scene, you’ll lose properties associated with the scene. typically, for example, you load the style sheet into the scene, so if you change the scene you’d lose CSS styling, or need to load the style sheet again. Similarly, you’d lost the background color, size, etc. so it really just depends on whether you want to keep those properties or replace them.

Comment: @James_D this is really useful. Have not used css styling yet, but probably will.

Comment: @James_D if you mean windows size by "size", is not that defined in Stage?

Comment: The scene has a width and height associated with it, which can be assigned via the constructor. Under some circumstances, calling `Stage.sizeToScene()` will use those values, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Stage.setScene()** changes the entire JFX appearance (like a theater when the stage is replaced by a new scene)
- **Scene.setRoot()** allows to switch the current scene to a new scene which is one of the scenes in a group.

Also If you switch the scene, you’ll lose properties associated with the scene. typically, for example, you load the style sheet into the scene, so if you change the scene you’d lose CSS styling, or need to load the style sheet again. Similarly, you’d lost the background color, size, etc. so it really just depends on whether you want to keep those properties or replace them.